# Trying to install the latest version of ubuntu (18.0.4, I think) without a cd or usb

Tags: system-installation

I tried using unetbootin but it didn't seem to be working, it'd boot into ubuntu but I wouldnt be able to actually install the operating system. 
Any ideas for installing this?

I would like to install it alongside windows 10. 
Edits : 
Would I be able to install ubuntu from a small 2gb partition on a secondary drive?

Comment: Please add more information regarding your problem, clarify `I wouldn't be able to actually install the operating system`.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is from 2018.April (hence 18.04) and is the latest LTS release, but not the latest release (18.10 from October that year for example).  I would check your download of the ISO, and even more importantly check your install media (there is an option for the system to do this to verify your write-to-thumb-drive worked).  This takes a couple of minutes, but can save hours-days of diagnosis & fixes when either of these steps being <100% is at fault.

Comment: Emmet, I meant that I could boot into Ubuntu but I was unable to permanently install it using the installer inside ubuntu.

Comment: I was using unetbootin to try to install it without a thumbdrive, I am currently not able to use a thumbdrive or a cd but I'm trying my best to get ubuntu installed despite this.